# grails paginate doesn't work

Tags: grails, pagination

I'm trying to use the paginate tag in grails but it isn't working.

in controller:

```
def show(Integer max) {
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
    def etpse
    def total

    if (params.data == 'all') {

        etpse = Enterprise.findAll()
        total = Enterprise.count()
    }

    else {
        def paramsLike = "%" + params.data + "%"
        etpse = Enterprise.findAllByKeywordLike(paramsLike)
        total = Enterprise.countByKeywordLike(paramsLike)
    }

    [etpseList: etpse, instanceTotal: total]
}
```

in gsp:

```
<div id='pagination'>
    <g:paginate total="${instanceTotal}" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `paginate` tag doesn't filter the results in your page, nor does it render the list of items. It merely creates links for the next/previous pages based on your request's parameters.

Your controller is responsible for fetching the correct page of data and your gsp is responsible for rendering the actual list of items.

The `paginate` tag parameters are designed to match the parameters to the GORM-injected `list` method and almost always go hand-in-hand:

```
class ItemController {
    def list() {
        [items: Item.list(params), itemCount: Item.count()]
    }
}
```

view:

```
<g:each var="item" in="${items}">
    <!-- render items here -->
</g:each>

<g:paginate controller="item" action="list" total="${itemCount}"/>
```

In the above code, the params list (including things like `max` and `offset`) is passed to the `list` method of the `Item` domain class, and this will grab a single page of data.

The paginate tag examines the request parameters for the same entries, determines *which page* of data you're viewing and creates the necessary links to the next and previous pages by using the correct values for max and offset.

Comment: What if the class is not a Domain class that comes with a list method? It is just a POGO? How to write such a list method?

Answer (score 2):

Here you go.

```
def show(Integer max) {

    Integer offset = params.int("offset")
    Integer max = Math.min(params.int("max") ?: 10, 100)

    if (params.data == 'all') {
        params.data = '%';
    }

    def c = Enterprise.createCriteria()
    def results = c.list(max: max, offset: offset) {
      ilike('keyword', "%" + params.data + "%")
    }


    [etpseList: results, instanceTotal: results.totalCount]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass your params max and offset into your findAll, otherwise Grails does not know how to paginate your resultset.

For example,

`Book.findAll(query, [max: 10, offset: 5])`