# Grails pagination not working

Tags: grails, gsp, pagination

I've been a week trying to fix this pagination problem, but with no good results,

I have this in my controller

```
    PatientController{
    def show(Long id) {
    def patientInstance = Patient.get(id)
    if (!patientInstance) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'patient.label', default: 'Patient'), id])
        return
    }



    def historyInstance = History.findAllByPatient(patientInstance)
    def total = historyInstance.size()


    [historyInstance: historyInstance,patientInstance: patientInstance,historyInstanceTotal: total]


    }
}
```

And I have this code on the view

```
    <g:each in="${historyInstance}" var="historyInstances" status="i">
      ...
    </g:each>

    <div class="pagination">
        <g:paginate  total="${historyInstanceTotal}"/>
    </div>
```

I used `params`, the max on the `<g:paginate>`, I tried everything but with no result it always shows the whole set of History in the view.

Comment: possible duplicate of [grails paginate doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17068081/grails-paginate-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 5):

You need to pass your `params` to the finder you're using, otherwise it won't know how to paginate. The `<g:paginate>` tag is only for displaying pagination links, not actually performing the pagination. Also the `total` will need to use a `countBy` because the result set will be limited to the current page of results.

```
def historyInstance = History.findAllByPatient(patientInstance, params)
def total = History.countByPatient(patientInstance)
```

Comment: There is no countAllBy, I tried but it shows an error, maybe the is another way rather than `findAllBy`, I heard that paginate only work with lists

Comment: `findAllBy` and `list` both return lists of domain objects.

Comment: When getting the count `historyInstance.countByPatient(patientInstance)` didn't work for me, however, `History.countByPatient(patientInstance)` did.

Comment: Thanks for catching that, @Bernardo